# how can i install Mass Editing in Odoo 12.0 in Windows

Tags: python, windows, odoo

[image]

Hi all i've a problem with **odoo 12.0** in Windows i've enabled Developer mode, then i past the folder in :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons

[image]

then i click on update apps list, i typed "mass" but nothing change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two things:

1. Remove the Apps filter in search box. Mass_editing is a module but not an application.
2. Make sure the mass_editing module you have is compatible with Odoo version 12. The one in Odoo.com apps (`mass_editing`) is up to Odoo version 10. There is a separate module (`mass_editing_v11`) for Odoo 11. I do not know if it works with 12 or if there is one available.

Consider also placing your addons in a separate addons directory, not the one that has standard Odoo addon modules. This makes it easier for you to update your Odoo and modules. Check your odoo.conf file for list of addons directories.

Comment: I think isn't compatible with Odoo version 12.0

addons_path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons